# Hacer que Script de division numerica de resultado con puntos en miles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un pequeño script que consegui por ahi el cual me realiza una division en tiempo real en 2 *inputs* pero necesito que el resultado salga de una vez con puntos en los miles ejemplo: si el resultado es `100000` que lo arroje como `100.000` sin pulsar otro boton ni nada si no automáticamente.

Este es el codigo que tengo y solo falta que haga lo de los puntos en los miles como explique antes

```js
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue)/parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
  
  if(!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('box3').value = result.toFixed(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box1" value="" onkeyup="sum();" /><br/>
<input  disabled type="hidden" id="box2" value="0.129" onkeyup="sum();" /><br/>
<input  type="text"  id="box3"  value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con `toLocaleString` que te devuelve una cadena con los indicadores de miles y decimales. Indica el idioma de tu localidad para obtener los caracteres correspondientes.

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```js
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue)/parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
  
  if(!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('box3').value = parseInt( result, 10 ).toLocaleString( "es-ES" );
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box1" value="" onkeyup="sum();" /><br/>
<input disabled type="hidden" id="box2" value="0.129" onkeyup="sum();" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="box3" value=""/>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString) que devuelve una cadena que tiene representación del número acorde al idioma. Puedes especificarle el idioma "es-ES" o si no cogerá el idioma por defecto del sistema operativo donde se ejecute la aplicación.

```js
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue)/parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
  
  if(!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('box3').value = result.toLocaleString();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box1" value="" onkeyup="sum();" /><br/>
<input  disabled type="hidden" id="box2" value="0.129" onkeyup="sum();" /><br/>
<input  type="text"  id="box3"  value=""/>
```